# Ascii to Binary is getting failed while extracting from mainframe server OS400

Tags: python, binary, airflow, ascii, ibm-midrange

We are trying to extract a files from AS400 / OS400 which is in Ascii mode and convert into readable format of binary mode. We have written below code

```
def retrlines(self, cmd, callback = None):
        resp = self.sendcmd('TYPE A')
        with self.transfercmd(cmd) as connectioninfo, \
                 connectioninfo.makefile('rt', encoding="cp500") as fp:
            while 1:
                line = fp.readline(self.maxline + 1)                 
                callback(line)
        return self.voidresp()
```

Getting an error
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

```
Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sftp_file_hook.py", line 418, in retrieve_file
    conn.retrlines(f'RETR {remote_file_name}', callback)
  File "/opt/ftplib.py", line 472, in retrlines
    callback(line)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Any suggestion please

Comment: Which line caused said TypeError? What is type of `self` in your snippet? What if any python packages are you using?

Comment: You seem to be reading a file in text mode ('rt'), and consequently passing a `str` to something (`callback`, at a guess) which ultimately expects binary data.  Since your file seems to be encoded with an 8-bit encoding (cp500), it _might_ be sufficient to encode `line` before passing it to `callback`.

Comment: Just an FYI, the AS400 is a mid-range system, in other words, a very souped up PC, and not a mainframe computer. Based on the analysis of the System/38 and System/36 that the AS/400 replaced, the only advantage is the hardened OS. Companies may still use mainframes in their original capacity. This is why JCL is a dying art.